# Ionic app crashes on Android emulator and device

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm building an app using the Ionic framework and AngularJS. It used to run fine, now it crashes as soon as it starts in both the emulator and an Android device. What is weird is that it runs fine in the Ionic View app (http://view.ionic.io/). The logcat says that the error is a NullPointerException.

What really worries me is that I didn't do any big changes, and another app started to fail as well. How can Ionic Cordova fail like that?

The complete logcat for the part of the crash says:

```
--------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227): Process: com.ionicframework.notpush921844, PID: 2227
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ionicframework.notpush921844/com.ionicframework.notpush921844.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.privateInitialize(java.lang.String, org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface, org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView, org.apache.cordova.CordovaPreferences)' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.privateInitialize(java.lang.String, org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface, org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView, org.apache.cordova.CordovaPreferences)' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:169)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.startupPlugins(PluginManager.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.init(PluginManager.java:84)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.init(CordovaWebViewImpl.java:116)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(CordovaActivity.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadUrl(CordovaActivity.java:209)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at com.ionicframework.notpush921844.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2227):    ... 10 more
W/ActivityManager( 1219):   Force finishing activity com.ionicframework.notpush921844/.MainActivity
I/WindowManager( 1219): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{f511ccd ActivityRecord{230d3264 u0 com.ionicframework.notpush921844/.MainActivity t61 f}} appWin=Window{1adfb8c9 u0 Starting com.ionicframework.notpush921844} drawState=4
E/ActivityManager( 1219): Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 576x576
D/OpenGLRenderer( 1219): Render dirty regions requested: true
D/Atlas   ( 1219): Validating map...
D/        ( 1219): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9de19530, tid 2264
I/OpenGLRenderer( 1219): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer( 1219): Enabling debug mode 0
W/EGL_emulation( 1219): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer( 1219): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9de3eb40, error=EGL_SUCCESS
W/ActivityManager( 1219): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{230d3264 u0 com.ionicframework.notpush921844/.MainActivity t61 f}
W/EGL_emulation( 1475): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer( 1475): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb0a93b40, error=EGL_SUCCESS
W/OpenGLRenderer( 1475): Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
W/OpenGLRenderer( 1475): Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
W/OpenGLRenderer( 1475): Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
I/iu.UploadsManager( 1746): End new media; added: 0, uploading: 0, time: 28 ms
V/ConfigFetchTask( 1746): ConfigFetchTask getDeviceDataVersionInfo(): ABFEt1ViXdAKZc6rqCAOLFv7YJuwVLSY9_n4gaUyYMJPnZLeFSYFobS5FdRKHo-hnBvGnh1pycqXDTZLbzD-k5JtupkV7UW73Ugga_ju-VhYkvWRtl_Jn90jZhoDq_QYlbboOgPzzxDKH54r4FIa2bH3M1p-U8uzShc-PuRzDfha4UOokdUFujGIG2kLo5vTf6UKiU8mrJ_i-n_s1sm2CNkFb7o3Q7f_N1keqlCKSvXmpOQwTd0C7WGOOCYVnk7105hhiah5iLKl_0ZmwnXt9YnD2hVSUAQyDJPeLsFPksOqBpS6WQgtxBQ
I/GoogleURLConnFactory( 1746): Using platform SSLCertificateSocketFactory
W/ActivityThread( 1746): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
I/ActivityManager( 1219): Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{39917cb u0 com.android.calendar/.alerts.InitAlarmsService}
I/ConfigFetchService( 1746): fetch service done; releasing wakelock
I/ConfigFetchService( 1746): stopping self
W/ActivityManager( 1219): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{230d3264 u0 com.ionicframework.notpush921844/.MainActivity t61 f}
I/CheckinService( 1746): Done disabling old GoogleServicesFramework version
I/ConfigService( 1598): onDestroy
D/TaskPersister( 1219): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=61_task.xml
D/InitAlarmsService( 2008): Clearing and rescheduling alarms.
I/ActivityManager( 1219): Killing 1538:com.android.printspooler/u0a42 (adj 15): empty #17
W/libprocessgroup( 1219): failed to open /acct/uid_10042/pid_1538/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
W/AudioTrack( 1219): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
I/Process ( 2227): Sending signal. PID: 2227 SIG: 9
I/ActivityManager( 1219): Process com.ionicframework.notpush921844 (pid 2227) has died
D/OpenGLRenderer( 1219): endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa2fe5880 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x9deaf750
W/InputMethodManagerService( 1219): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@2a47c778 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@344958d4
```

Comment: What really worries me is that I didn't do any big changes ? have you passed your project to Crossover  ? (personnaly, crossover crashes all my projects ;) ) have you add / remove cordova plugins ? I suggest you to ionic platform rm android & ionic platform add android before rebuild

Comment: You were right, it was that. It works fine now, thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out the problem was caused by adding Phonegap's PushPlugin. I just had to remove android platform with **ionic platform rm android** and then add it again with **ionic platform add android**. Works fine now in both emulator and device.