# phonegap project to android gradle project

Tags: java, android, apache, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am converting the PhoneGap project to the gradle project with the help of the below link:

http://www.catharinegeek.com/embed-cordova-webview-in-android-native-app/

but i am getting the error while opening the app

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sellout.selloutzone.sellout/com.sellout.selloutzone.sellout.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.privateInitialize(java.lang.String, org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface, org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView, org.apache.cordova.CordovaPreferences)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3190)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.privateInitialize(java.lang.String, org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface, org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView, org.apache.cordova.CordovaPreferences)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:172)
                                                                                   at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.startupPlugins(PluginManager.java:98)
                                                                                   at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.init(PluginManager.java:87)
                                                                                   at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.init(CordovaWebViewImpl.java:116)
                                                                                   at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(CordovaActivity.java:144)
                                                                                   at com.sellout.selloutzone.sellout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)**
i had searched everywhere followed these links too but no luck please help me out friends i am searching for solution for morethan 2days

https://github.com/jimmykobe1171/EmbeddedCorovaWebViewDemo/tree/master/EmbeddedCordovaWebViewDemo/app/src/main

[Unfortunately cordova android App Stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668069/unfortunately-cordova-android-app-stopped)

[Ionic app crashes on Android emulator and device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130216/ionic-app-crashes-on-android-emulator-and-device)

[image: this is project structure]

Comment: Could you post the complete error trace? Also the logcat trace plz.

Comment: updated my post plz go through it